# Custom font displays artifacts

Tags: android, view, fonts, artifact

I use a custom font for my application. The code is really simple to integrate it :

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),
            "fonts/PermanentMarker.ttf");
    textview.setTypeface(tf);
```

However I have artifacts with some of my TextViews : http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg11/scaled.php?server=11&filename=screenshot2012050621514.png&res=landing

I don't really know where it is coming from. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Sorry its hard to tell what your question is about. Be more specific

Comment: Look at the picture : http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg11/scaled.php?server=11&filename=screenshot2012050621514.png&res=landing
There are some strange characters and I don't know where they are coming from

Comment: Is this on an emulator or a real device? Try another font and see if it has the same issues.

Comment: Maybe they are in the original font too?

Comment: I have tried with other fonts (including the classical Roboto) and with others phones. It is the same behavior

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from hardware acceleration. When forcing the TextView to use software rending, everything become fine.

Comment: Do you have any idea why this happens? I'd like to keep hardware acceleration enabled but this issue keeps coming up for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and made sure that it's not related to API level 21 view elevations, as it also appears below API-21.

For me a single artifact appears near the end/right edge of the `TextView` without intersecting with the text itself.

**I didn't came up with a root solution, but I had a work around:** I laid a dummy view on top of the `TextView` that has the same background style as the `TextView` and constrained it to the end of the `TextView` with the width that equals to the artifact width, and a height that equals to the `TextView`.

If your `TextView` / `Button` that holds the special font is clickable, you need to set `android:clickable="false"` to the dummy view